# Error when trying to render animation with julialang

Tags: animation, julia

I am trying to get into animations using the Plots package. I am following this tutorial: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/animations/

However when trying to execute the program I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: failed process: Process(`/home/olep/.julia/artifacts/7f40eeb66d90d3026ae5fb68761c263b57adb840/bin/ffmpeg -v 16 -framerate 3 -i /tmp/jl_h1sGUw/%06d.png -i /tmp/jl_h1sGUw/palette.bmp -lavfi paletteuse=dither=sierra2_4a -loop 0 -y /home/olep/Documents/Studium/Semester2/tutorial_anim_fps30.gif`, ProcessSignaled(11)) [0]

Stacktrace:
  [1] run
    @ ./process.jl:438 [inlined]
  [2] (::FFMPEG.var"#4#6"{Cmd})(command_path::String)
    @ FFMPEG ~/.julia/packages/FFMPEG/aazvf/src/FFMPEG.jl:114
  [3] (::JLLWrappers.var"#2#3"{FFMPEG.var"#4#6"{Cmd}, String})()
    @ JLLWrappers ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/bkwIo/src/runtime.jl:49
  [4] withenv(::JLLWrappers.var"#2#3"{FFMPEG.var"#4#6"{Cmd}, String}, ::Pair{String, String}, ::Vararg{Pair{String, String}, N} where N)
    @ Base ./env.jl:161
  [5] withenv_executable_wrapper(f::Function, executable_path::String, PATH::String, LIBPATH::String, adjust_PATH::Bool, adjust_LIBPATH::Bool)
    @ JLLWrappers ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/bkwIo/src/runtime.jl:48
  [6] #invokelatest#2
    @ ./essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
  [7] invokelatest
    @ ./essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
  [8] #ffmpeg#7
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/bkwIo/src/products/executable_generators.jl:7 [inlined]
  [9] ffmpeg
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/bkwIo/src/products/executable_generators.jl:7 [inlined]
 [10] #exe#2
    @ ~/.julia/packages/FFMPEG/aazvf/src/FFMPEG.jl:113 [inlined]
 [11] ffmpeg_exe
    @ ~/.julia/packages/FFMPEG/aazvf/src/FFMPEG.jl:125 [inlined]
 [12] buildanimation(anim::Animation, fn::String, is_animated_gif::Bool; fps::Int64, loop::Int64, variable_palette::Bool, verbose::Bool, show_msg::Bool)
    @ Plots ~/.julia/packages/Plots/vVVub/src/animation.jl:98
 [13] #gif#232
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Plots/vVVub/src/animation.jl:64 [inlined]
 [14] top-level scope
    @ ~/Documents/Studium/Semester2/EM2/HW/01/animTest.jl:11
in expression starting at /home/olep/Documents/Studium/Semester2/EM2/HW/01/animTest.jl:11
```

I am on manjaro (Arch linux).
Any ideas what’s going wrong?

Comment: did you install Julia via system package manager? It is recommended you install https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/julia-bin instead to avoid library issue.

Comment: This did indeed fix it! To we have a way to prevent future users from this error? Could we for example open an issue in the manjaro forum so that they update/remove the julia package?

Answer (score 1):

Manjaro:

Reinstall `julia` -> `julia-bin`

```
sudo pamac install julia-bin
```